# How to avoid warning message when getting user information on Next.js 13 server components with Auth0

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, auth0

I'm trying to move a Next.js app with Auth0 authentication to the new app router. I understand the limitations of server components not being able to write cookies, but I'm getting a message that is confusing.

My understanding is that if I need to get user info on a server component, I need to use the `'getSession'` function from `'@auth0/nextjs-auth0'`, which is not available for client components.

However, every time I call it, the server console logs the following message (not labeled as an error or warning): `"nextjs-auth0 is attempting to set cookies from a server component"`.

I am not trying to set any cookies, only get the user information. Can anyone help me understand why this call to `'getSession'` makes the component set cookies? Also, is it safe to ignore this message if I'm not really trying to set cookies?

Thanks in advance.

**Added code:** the complete solution is somewhat complex but this code illustrates my question. This is a simple SSR component that gets the user name from the server session (as specified in Auth0's format):

```
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

export default async function Profile() {
    const session = await getSession();

    return (
    <div>
        HELLO {session?.user?.name}
    </div>
    )
}
```

In the above code, every time `getSession` is called the server console emits the message `"nextjs-auth0 is attempting to set cookies from a server component"`.

I'm not explicitly trying to set cookies, just get the user's information. I would like to understand why this happens and what are the effects of ignoring the message.

Again, thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you share your code for better understanding your question?

Comment: Hello @KannuMandora, thanks for the quick reply. I have amended my question with the code for the relevant server-side component.

Answer (score 9):

I was perplexed by this, too, so I stepped through the code associated with `getSession` (in my case, this was being called by `withPageAuthRequired`). It looks like, because of default configuration in `@auth0/nextjs-auth0`, any time you access the cached session on your server, an attempt is made to automatically set new cookies (code [here](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/0f25568ebdb35326cf95c97f1d58ec10ae3e6d0c/src/session/cache.ts#L116-L118)). I stopped this behavior and the warning with `AUTH0_SESSION_AUTO_SAVE=false` after finding [this](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/pull/1116) PR. If we decide to reenable rolling sessions in our project, I'll follow the advice [here](https://auth0.github.io/nextjs-auth0/types/session_touch_session.TouchSession.html).